# How to move PieChart of circle to the right in MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to move the circle to the right so that the legend fits without overlapping. How to do it?
[Current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdufi.jpg)

```
chart.centerCircleBox.x += 100f
```

does not work.

Comment: provide more details, like what library you are using to show PieChart, if it is a custom view show us the code.

Comment: I use MPAndroidChart library.

Comment: take a loot at this example https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java

Comment: I saw this code, but my question is not resolved in it.